# ListView with MultiChoice selection in Android in order they were selected

Tags: android, listview, multi-select

I am Trying follwoing code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private ListView list;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  final String[] items = { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4",
    "item 5", "item 6", "item 7" };
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);

  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
  list.setAdapter(adapter);
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    String checkedItems = displayCheckedItems(list
      .getCheckedItemPositions());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkedItems,
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }

  });
 }

 /**
  * The method checks the SparseBooleanArray in order to return String
  * representation with the names of the checked items
  * 
  * @param checkedItems
  * @return String
  */
 private String displayCheckedItems(SparseBooleanArray checkedItems) {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
  for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++) {

   if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
    int idx = checkedItems.keyAt(i);

    if (sb.length() > 0)
     sb.append(", ");

    String s = (String) list.getAdapter().getItem(idx);
    sb.append(s);

   }
  }

  return sb.toString();
 }
}
```

this gives me the selected items in the order that they are present in the original `String[] items`

however  I want to get items in the order I have selected them

for example

"item 7", "item 3", "item 1",

the order in which it was selected by me and **not like**

"item 1", "item 3", "item 7",

how can this be done

Comment: when u select a checkbox, add that position to an array, when u uncheck it, remove the position from array. Finally, at the end you will have array containing the position if items in the order you selected

Comment: i tried that logic with `getCheckedItemPosition`  NOT `getCheckedItemPositions` but I am not getting the selected item position that I can add to array any way to do this

Comment: implement custom click listener to the checkbox, you can obtain the position

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check every time if the element exist or not in string, if not you can add new value to tmp string;
result is :

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String tmp = Sort(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(tmp),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
private String Sort(String tmp){

        if (order.contains(tmp)){
            Log.d("contain","contain");
            order = order.replace(","+tmp,"");
        }else if (order.length() == 0){
            order +=  tmp;
        }else {
            order +=  ","+tmp;
        }
        return order;
    }
```